# Iterated function with $a_{n} = {F^{2n}(1)} $ and $b_{n} = {F^{2n+1}(1) }$. How to show that $a_n$ is increasing and $b_n$ is decreasing?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, iterated-function-system

Consider function $ F(x) = \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}$. Let $a_{n} = {F^{2n}(1)} $ and $b_{n} = {F^{2n+1}(1) }$ . How can I show that $ a_{n} $ is increasing and $b_{n} $ is decreasing and what is their limit ?

Comment: I don't understand your notation $F^{n}(x) = \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}$. Why do you need $n$ to define your function ? Why not $F(x) = \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}$. Then we take $F(1), F(F(1))...$.

Comment: because in that case if I wanted to show the nth term of An i should write F(F(F(F(F(.....x)))...), but this way it's easier to write $a_{n}$ = $F^{2n}(x)$.

Comment: I insist: please use correct terms : a function is not "iterative" by itself. You define it first, then you use it for an iteration. Besides, do you have an idea of attack of this issue ? Do you have an idea of the value of the (common) limit of the two sequences ?

Comment: Hint: The common limit is a root of the "fixed point equation" $x=F(x) \iff x=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}} \iff x^3=x+1$ which is $\approx 1.324718$ (a so-called Pisot number). You can check it by simulation.